# How to find iOS locale hierarchy

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization, locale

The iOS system automatically picks the most suitable available localization for an app. For instance, when the user's locale is `en-IN` but the app only offers `en-GB`, that'll act as a fallback (as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/201/)).

My question is: Is it possible to look up these hierarchies somewhere?

The reasoning behind this question is that, for instance, I may have translations in `es-CO`, `es-CL`, `es-PE`, ... that are almost identical and instead of including separate string files for all of them, I'd like to just provide them for one common fallback locale. I know that I could simply use `es-419` in this exemplary case but it might not be that obvious in other scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself here:

```
Bundle.preferredLocalizations(
    from: ["es", "es-419", "es-AR", "es-CL", "es-CO", "es-MX", "es-PE"],
    forPreferences: ["es-PE"])
```

returns `["es-PE", "es-419", "es"]` which means Peruvian Spanish fill fall back to `es-419` and `es` in order.